# checking if two collections have a common member with jest

Tags: javascript, arrays, jestjs

I want an expect expression which tests an array contains a specific object or not.

I can do it with this code:

```
expect(insensitiveKeys.some(val => resultKeys.indexOf(val) !== -1)).toBe(false)
```

it checks that if any instance in resultKeys is in insensitiveKeys or not.

But I want a method of jest to do it.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr1 = ['apple','orange',1]

let commonItems = arr1.filter((item) => {return arr.indexOf(item) != -1});
```

commonItems will return [1]

You can use commonItems.length in your expect statement.